# How do you store VS2015 dll symbols in the cache?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[Visual Studio Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqEXh.png)

[Project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEBDa.png)

I've set up symbol loading, but it stores all the symbols in my project folder, which is getting bogged down. What do I need to change to make it use the cache I assigned?

Comment: What symbols are you expecting to go to the cache folder about?

Comment: I was expecting all the `pdb` files to be going to the cache folder.